# Calling wp_localize_script in a different function

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-localize-script

I am trying to localize a variable in a javascript below.. The scenario is that I want to dynamically get the post_id and localize it in the jquery I have enqueued through wp_enqueue_scripts. Here's my code:

```
function add_scripts() {
     wp_enqueue_style('jplayercss',plugins_url( 'skin/jplayer.blue.monday.css',__FILE__));
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jplayer',plugins_url( 'js/jquery.jplayer.min.js' , __FILE__ ) );
     wp_enqueue_script( 'jplayerjs',plugins_url( 'js/mfsjplayer.js',__FILE__), array('jquery') ); 
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

and  i am calling it in a different function in the content_filter hook,

```
function the_content_filter( $content ) {

    $post_id        =  $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
    $accessToken    = get_option( 'dropbox_api_token' );
    $dbxClient      = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
    $file_url_array = $dbxClient->createTemporaryDirectLink( "/recorded_file".$post_id.".wav" );
    $file_url       = isset( $file_url_array ) ? $file_url_array[0] : '';
    if ( ! empty( $file_url ) ) {
        require("lib/mfs_jplayer_interface.php");   
        $site_parameters = array(
              'file_url' => $file_url,
              'plugin_url' => plugins_url(),
              'theme_directory' => get_template_directory_uri(),
              'post_id' => $post_id,
        ); 
        $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
        $upload_loc = $upload_dir['baseurl']."/recorded_files";
        wp_localize_script( 'jplayerjs', 'mfs_var', $site_parameters ); 
    }
// Add play and record buttons to each post
// Returns the content.
return $content;
}
 add_filter( 'the_content', 'the_content_filter', 20 );
```

So I am getting mfs_var as undefined variable in console. Please can anyone help me in solving the issue. Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_content` filter is (most likely) running long after you scripts were output.

You need to either:

1. Run localize logic earlier.
2. Enqueue scripts for footer, using respective `wp_enqueue_script()` argument.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst, it worked. But when i alert mfs_var.post_id, it gets the post_id of only the first post rather than alerting all the post_ids of each posts..